# AWS CloudWatch alarm for infrequently executed process

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I have a process that runs once every 24 hours (data pipeline). I want to monitor it for failures, but am having trouble defining an alarm that works adequately.

Since the process runs only once every 24 hours, there can be 1 failure every 24 hours at most.

If I define a short period (e.g. 5 minutes), then the alarm will flip back to OK status after 5 minutes, as there are no more errors.

If I define a period of 24 hours, then the alarm will be stuck in ERROR status until the period passes, even if I re-run the process manually and it succeeds, because "one error within 24 hour period" is still true.

How do I get an alarm on failure, but clear it once the process succeeds?

Comment: " there are no more errors" - what does it mean? There is an error, you get notification, and then its back to normal.

Comment: What I mean is that the resource is no longer in an alarm state. So if one was to login into AWS to investigate, and look at the alarms, there will be none.

Comment: There is an option on how to treat missing data in cloudwatch.
If you would like to it to recover after a failure you can define treating missing data as good or bad. How much time would you like it to stay in ERROR status?

Comment: @Yanir But the data is not missing. It just runs very infrequently. I want it to recover after I manually re-ran the process or stay in alarm until I do.